# How to get Jenkins build details in parameters using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to get build display name as "Active Choices Parameter" in Jenkins parameter name DISPLAY_NAME using below groovy script, but the output is coming null in parameters. And when I try to run directly in groovy I get the expected output, could someone please suggest on why the parameter is not able to fetch the result ?

println Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Folder1/folder2/jenkins-project").getLastSuccessfulBuild().displayName

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

                    try {
                        def job=Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Folder1/folder2/jenkins-project")
                        def displayname=job.getLastSuccessfulBuild().displayName
                        return displayname
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        return [e.toString()]
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the Display Name correctly? The following works perfectly for me.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "$JOB_NAME"
                    def displayname=Jenkins.instance.getItem("$JOB_NAME").getLastSuccessfulBuild().displayName
                    echo "displayname $displayname"
                
                }
        }
       
    }
}
  post {
        success {
            script{
                // Here I'm setting a DisplayName
                currentBuild.displayName = "D-$BUILD_ID"
            }
        }
    }
}
```